# Assigning first-responder status failed

Tags: objective-c, first-responder

I have a little application with two views. What I don't understand is that I can't seemed to manage how I can manually assign the first responder status to a particular view.

I have this code in awakeFromNib method.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
NSView *a = [[firstView alloc]init];
NSView *b = [[secondVIew alloc]init];

[b becomeFirstResponder];
[a resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would resign first before becoming first responder.

For a more detailed answer we need to know the layout of the view in relation to the view controller. Typically, you assign firstResponder in a viewcontroller. Since you are overriding awakeFromNib its clear that this snippet isn't in a viewController.

Lastly, don't forget to call super.